# Is to possible to do speech to text with the speakers In python

Tags: python, speech

I am trying to make a project in python 3.7 that listens if any audio is playing and if it does then convert it to text so it can type it out. If it helps, it is only one word at a time. I would normally put some code that I have already done but I have absolutely no idea :|. All I know is using the keyboard module to type

Input: my computer playing "testing"
Output: testing being typed

What do you think?

Comment: please provide your code or library that you used

Comment: you can try pocketsphinx python library to  get started. What you want to do, consists of many parts. Record an audio - stop when it detects a silence and feed the audio input to an engine that then converts it into words of your choice.

Comment: https://www.simplifiedpython.net/speech-recognition-python/

Comment: @Siyanew , i have no idea of anything to do with this ort of stuff

Comment: @Luv Yes, that would work but the point for me is speed, it will hear a spelling - then type it

Comment: That is a good place to start then proceed to breaking audio while continuously recording into chunks that separate words and using those to detect at a faster clip. It is a complicated problem but it is a good learning. Can you try recording and feeding samples into a queue where a worker breaks and writes audio chunks 1 file per  spoken word? once you perfect that then you convert audio to letters.